# C++ -- Adding elements to private member field std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, size, field, push-back

```
class T {
private:
  std::vector<T> myVec;
  // ...
public:
  T();
  T(float x, float y);
  std::vector<T> getMyVec() { return myVec; }
  // ...
};
```

// in T.cpp I don't use myVec in any way (not in the constructor either)

// in Tmain.cpp:

```
int main() {
  T myT;
  std::cout << myT.getMyVec().size() << std::endl; // 0
  T anotherT(1.1, 2.2);
  myT.getMyVec().push_back(anotherT);
  std::cout << myT.getMyVec().size() << std::endl; // 0
}
```

Hopefully I can make myself clear (just assume that my #include's etc. are correct):

So basically, I have a class **T** in which I have a private member field named **myVec** which is of type **std::vector**. I also have a public (get-)function to access that field.
In main I create myself a T object, and print out its **myVec.size()**. It's zero as I haven't done anything to the vector yet. I create **anotherT** object and **push_back()** it to my vector field of the previous T object.
Again I print out the **myVec.size()** of the former object (I expect it to be 1 at this point, as I've added **anotherT** to it. But it still returns 0 as its size. Why is that? And how can I make it so that it "saves" the objects I try to add to it?

Comment: Hint 1): Your getter returns a copy. Hint 2) if you want to expose the private member so that is tan be written to, you might as well make it public. Hint 3) Maybe you need a method `void add_element(float x);` that adds the element to your private vector.

Comment: Hint 3): Read about C++ references. You are destroying encapsulation with that though and making the member public is effectively the same.

Comment: You will run into problems if you later decide to use a different container (such as list or queue) instead of a vector. Don't expose your implementation in the interface. Provide a method to add elements to your vector, if the implementation changes in future, only that method needs to change, and not the calling code.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. All answers were quite useful. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Beko If your question is answered, accept one of the answers. Don't edit the question title.

Comment: @Happy Ah, didn't know that. Done^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector<T> getMyVec() { return myVec; }
```

should be

```
std::vector<T>& getMyVec() { return myVec; }
```

else you return a copy of your member.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a reference to your private vector.

```
std::vector<T>& getMyVec() { return myVec; }
```

Else it will return a copy. And whatever changes you make to the copy will not affect your vector in the class.

Comment: Huh? Downvoted for what reason?

Comment: Maybe because the first version was wrong, and the second version doesn't add anything to the other answer.

Comment: I saw the other answer after I posted this answer.

Comment: both answers have a downvote, maybe Mr. Silent Serial Downvoter is back in town